# How to control my app's version?

Tags: android

I  want to control my customer's app's version. If the  application is not update ,i want to show  them an alert message that "your app isn't update  would you like to update ?" how  can  i  control this in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host your new version apk file in web page with a text file with version information.Then palce a text file in assest with current version information. When you application starts, read current version from assest, download the version information using HTTP methods and compare the version. If you require update then download latest apk from web using HTTP method and install using following code..

```
Intent apk_installer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
apk_installer.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFilePath),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivityForResult(apk_installer,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current apk/Programm version by:

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
currentVersion = info.versionCode;
currentName = info.versionName;
```

So you don't really need a local text file with version information.

Greetings Ralf